# Magic square operator's measurement product

Tags: entanglement, nonlocal-games

In the talk by Andrea Coladangelo ([link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pO-mzsZuCYo)) at 29:30, he claims that if $X_1X_2X_3 = I$, such that the operators commute. Then, the product of the measurement results on an EPR pair of the same dimension as the operator would be $1$.

If $x_i$ is the measurement result of measuring $X_i$ then $x_1x_2x_3 = 1$. Can someone please explain me how would one go about in proving this?

The Wikipedia page for the same ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_pseudo-telepathy#The_magic_square_game)) provides the operators for which this property holds.

#### State

The state for magic square would be:
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} 
\bigg( 
|+\rangle \otimes |+\rangle + 
|-\rangle \otimes |-\rangle 
\bigg)
$$

Alice and Bob share total of two copies of the above state. The states $|+\rangle$ and $|-\rangle$ are eigenstates with eigenvalues $\pm 1$

#### Measurements

You can refer to the Wikipedia page to for the complete grid, but for the sake of this question I have taken one column
$$
X_1 = I \otimes Z \\
X_2 = X \otimes I \\
X_3 = X \otimes Z
$$
The operators commute

Comment: I guess the rough idea is probably that if we have commuting measurements it doesn't matter in which order we measure them, they'd give the same probabilities. I haven't looked at the video. It would be nice if you could write out the question explicitly, without needing to refer to the video.